# No attribute find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from the website but the script I wrote generates an error in the last line of this block. That it has no attribute "find_all". Kindly tell me how to change it so it works.

```python
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pickle

def url_to_transcript(url):
    '''Returns transcript data specifically from scrapsfromtheloft.com.'''
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    text = [p.text for p in soup.find(class_="post-content").find_all('p')]
    print(url)
    return text
    
# URLs of transcripts in scope
urls = ['http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/05/06/louis-ck-oh-my-god-full-transcript/',
        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/04/11/dave-chappelle-age-spin-2017-full-transcript/',
        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2018/03/15/ricky-gervais-humanity-transcript/',
        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/08/07/bo-burnham-2013-full-transcript/',
        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/05/24/bill-burr-im-sorry-feel-way-2014-full-transcript/',
        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/04/21/jim-jefferies-bare-2014-full-transcript/',
        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/08/02/john-mulaney-comeback-kid-2015-full-transcript/',
        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/10/21/hasan-minhaj-homecoming-king-2017-full-transcript/',
        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/09/19/ali-wong-baby-cobra-2016-full-transcript/',
        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/08/03/anthony-jeselnik-thoughts-prayers-2015-full-transcript/',
        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2018/03/03/mike-birbiglia-my-girlfriends-boyfriend-2013-full-transcript/',
        'http://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2017/08/19/joe-rogan-triggered-2016-full-transcript/']
    
# Comedian names
comedians = ['louis', 'dave', 'ricky', 'bo', 'bill', 'jim', 'john', 'hasan', 'ali', 'anthony', 'mike', 'joe']
    
transcripts = [url_to_transcript(u) for u in urls]
```

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: The error is telling you whats up.  the find_all method is being invoked on a NoneType.   you got that from the prior function call.   you got nothing back from the function that preceeds the find_all call.   correct that and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `'elementor-widget-theme-post-content'` instead of `'post-content'` if you inspect the html elements on the page.

i.e. you need to change the line from

```
text = [p.text for p in soup.find(class_="post-content").find_all('p')]
```

to

```
text = [p.text for p in soup.find(class_="elementor-widget-theme-post-content").find_all('p')]
```